# PyQT -- How can you make a QTreeview uneditable but also selectable?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I just switched from wxPython to PyQT and I am having some trouble with the QTreeview.  I have a QTreeview that will display data categorized into sections that are expandable, but the data in this TreeView should not be editable, but I need to be able to have the user select the data (doubleclicking is going to execute another method).  I am not certain how to make it readonly but also selectable.  I am using the QStandardItemModel with the QStandardItem to hold the data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set individual items to be uneditable by doing this when you create the `QSandardItem`

```
item = QStandardItem('my_item_text')
item.setEditable(False)
```

You can disable editing for the entire treeview by calling

```
my_treeview.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
```

By default the treeview should allow you to select items, but if you want to change the default behaviour you will want to look at the `setSelectionMode()` and `setSelectionBehavior()` methods of the treeview (well they are for `QAbstractItemView` which `QTreeView` inherits from). c++ documentation for these methods can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop) which I generally use over the PyQt documentation as it is often more complete, and it isn't too difficult to translate into Python code. Just replace all instances of `::` with `.`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  This worked just liked I needed it to.  I also found that you can do something like this 'item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)' and it will give you the same behavior.  But the disabling of editing for the whole treeview at once is better.

Comment: No problem! I'm pretty sure `item.setEditable()` wraps `item.setFlags()` at the low level, but without overwriting the existing set of flags that don't relate to editing.